# HttpCompileException in ASP.Net MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on an ASP.Net MVC E-commerce project. I am receiving the following exception.

[image]

What is the reason for this exception?

Partial code:

[image]

[Third Image here][3]

Comment: Your image does not show.

Comment: Something is wrong with your _ProductsView partial.

Comment: There is a wrong in "_ProductsView partial". I uploaded photo

Comment: will fix your problem in the 2nd image `@model IEnumerable<Ecommerce.Models.Product>`

Comment: Please, please add the code to your question as **text** rather than an image. It makes it so much harder for people to help you if they have to click on an image, squint to read the code, then maybe type the code in on their own computer to try/fix it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

a `foreach` loop needs a definition of some kind of collection (`List`, `IEnumerable`, etc).

So in order to fix the issue with your partial view.. at the top you need

```
@model IEnumerable<Ecommerce.Models.Products>
```

then in your main view add

```
@Html.Partial("_ProductsView", Model)
```

so then your foreach is reading.. 'Foreach item in the List of Products' .... perform this operation

Comment: I send to you my project. Could I help me?

Comment: And once you fix that you will likely get a new error at @Html.Partial("_ProductsView") because you aren't passing the actual list model to the partial.  That call needs to be @Html.Partial("_ProductsView", Model)

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid Yes. Could you help me? I can't fix a matter

Comment: @SezerTürkdal post what the error is in your question, with my correction

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm late for respond. There is a NullReferenceException error at now. How Am I fix that matter?

Comment: @SezerTürkdal I am unable to see your third image.

Answer (score 0):

With reference of your image its clearing visible that you have forgotten to pass modal to partial view and since the model value is null and if you try iterate so it will throw null object exception. To fix it use following approach.

Replace `@Html.Partial("_ProductsView") to @Html.Partial("_ProductsView", Model)` in your view and again make sure you are passing model from controller.

One more thing before iterating list do a null check

```
@if(modal != null)
{
   //do your stuff
}
```